# when button clicked show a jquery datatable modal dialog box not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a table("sqlresultsactive") generated on page load. when I click a button "btnSelectProduct" on that page it shows a modal dialog box which contains that table.

In script I used
[jquery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zITnj.png)  [table before & after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgYpG.png)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#sqlresultsactive').DataTable();
}); 

<asp:GridView ID="sqlresultsactive" runat="server" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" Width="100%" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" ClientIDMode="Static" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Font-Size="10px" OnRowCommand="sqlresultsactive_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="sqlresultsactive_RowDataBound">
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" ItemStyle-Width="10%">
      <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Button ID="ButtonSelect" class="btn btn-success btn-sm p-0" runat="server" Width="60px" CommandName="SwitchProduct" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "webuniqueid") %>' Text="Select"></asp:Button><%--data-dismiss="modal"--%>
          <asp:HiddenField ID="BusinessSegment" runat="server" Value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "BusinessSegment") %>' />
      </ItemTemplate>
      <FooterTemplate>
      </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Product" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" ItemStyle-Width="20%">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblProduct" runat="server" Text='<%#FormatStringValues(Container.DataItem("programName").ToString, "string")%>' CssClass="nobr"></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <FooterTemplate>
      </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Premium Finance" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" ItemStyle-Width="20%">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <%--<div id="tdHeadPremiumFinance">--%>
        <div align="center" id="tdPremiumFinance" runat="server">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="PremiumFinanceCheckBox" CssClass="checkbox" Visible="false" runat="server" />
            <asp:Label ID="PremiumFinanceWebUniqueId" runat="server" Text='<%#FormatStringValues(Container.DataItem("webuniqueid").ToString, "string")%>' Visible="false" CssClass="nobr"></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <%--</div>--%>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <FooterTemplate>
      </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Company" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" ItemStyle-Width="30%">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <span><%#SplitCompany(FormatStringValues(Container.DataItem("company").ToString, "string"), "Company")%></span>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <FooterTemplate>
      </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Dealer" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" ItemStyle-Width="20%">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="dealerLabel" runat="server" Text='<%#FormatStringValues(Container.DataItem("dealernumber").ToString, "string")%>' CssClass="nobr"></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <FooterTemplate>
      </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

on document and added their source files but still it does not works.
the table is shown but pagination and grid search etc.. are not showing

Comment: I see JavaScript/jQuery code and no corresponding tags and I see a VB.NET tag and no corresponding code. Please apply all relevant tags and no irrelevant ones.

Comment: Holy c**p man, format your code.

Comment: "it shows a modal dialog box which contains that table." try to show the modal, then init table $('#sqlresultsactive').DataTable();. I mean call $('#sqlresultsactive').DataTable(); when modal's already shown

Comment: my table is showing but it doesnot have any pagination or grid search or anything

Comment: i tried a simple example code it works but for my table it does not. on document .ready when i put it like this $('#sqlresultsactive').DataTable(); and $('#example').DataTable(); it does not work for example table

Comment: i believe i have a error in my grid somewhere maybe in binding data

Answer (score 0):

I hope that it will work after following change

```
$('#sqlresultsactive').DataTable({
  **"dom": "lrBftip",**
});
```

*Another Option you can try:*
on button click then bind the `DataTable`